# Lighweight markup (wiki) language for documenting

Tags: latex, wiki, openoffice.org, markup

When I write papers or documentation it makes think using LaTeX or OpenOffice is overkill as I usually only need some markup elements (bold, headlines, lists, ...) . I'd like to write my documents using a wiki style markup as this is very efficient.

For example:

```
= Introduction =
'''HTML''' is a markup language...
```

In the end I'd like to simply convert it to PDF. (Cross-platform was nice too.)

```
compiler.exe -pdf input.wiki output.pdf
```

Is there a tool (or simple tool chain)  to do this job?

I'd personally like to *not* make use of LaTeX as a transformation step. There are tools doing this job transforming lightweight syntax to TeX and then to PDF/PS.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You might find that [MarkDown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) gets pretty close to what you want.

MarkDown is a simple technique for marking up text files so that they can be post-processed into other forms. One of the nice things about MarkDown is their goal that a marked-up document should be simply readable as a straight text file:

> The overriding design goal for
>   Markdown’s formatting syntax is to
>   make it as readable as possible. The
>   idea is that a Markdown-formatted
>   document should be publishable as-is,
>   as plain text, without looking like
>   it’s been marked up with tags or
>   formatting instructions.

[PanDoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) looks like it might be good companian tool to convert the MarkDown straight into PDF files. There may well be other choices - PanDoc is just the best tool I found with a quick Google search.

Comment: He was faster ;-) Tried Pandoc and it looks very promising.

Answer (score 12):

[reStructuredText](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText).

You can use [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) to generate HTML and LaTeX (and later PDF with pdflatex).

There is also [rst2pdf](http://code.google.com/p/rst2pdf/), don't know if it's mature.

Answer (score 9):

You could use [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) ([example](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/basics)) and then use [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) (which also works with reStructuredText and several other wiki-like syntaxes) to convert to PDF.

Comment: Can Pandoc be used in web browser as is (like we can use MathJax in a browser) ?