# How can I mix LaTeX in with Markdown?

Tags: html, latex, markdown, mathematical-typesetting

I've been using Markdown for class notes, and it's great.  I even do some preprocessing on the Markdown so I can do things like tables.  But this term I'm teaching a class with a lot of math, and I'd love to be able to put LaTeX formulas with Markdown, something like this:

```latex
The refinement relation is written $a \sqsubseteq b$, which can be 
pronounced "$a$ approximates $b$" or "$b$ is at least as defined as $a$".
```

I'd like to be able to take each fragment of LaTeX and preprocess it into a nice antialiased PNG file which I could then include in my Markdown via the HTML `<img>` tag.  But I have absolutely no idea how to take a fragment of LaTeX and get a nice image that

- Has the right bounding box
- Is antialiased

All I know how to do is get full pages in DVI, PostScript, or PDF formats.

I'm sure this problem has been addressed, but I haven't been able to guess the right search terms.  Any suggestions how to solve it or where to look for an existing solution?

---

**EDIT**: Having installed mathTeX, I can say that the code is inflexible, that it violates the Linux Filesystem Hierarchy standard, and that it is amateur work—in both the good and bad senses of that word.  The code is so complex that there are no obvious faults.  I will be looking for alternatives.

Also, it's clear that at bottom, solutions are based on [`dvipng`](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/dvipng/).

---

**ONE YEAR LATER**: I never did get the seamless integration I had been hoping for, but I am limping along on a script of my own devising.  It turns out that instead of `dvipng` it is a little easier to use `dvips -E` and the `convert` program of ImageMagick.  The benefits are slightly more control of things like scaling, and ease of making a transparent background.
The curious can inspect [this example](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/105-2011s/notes.html).

I can't recommend this solution to anyone.  But I can't recommend MathTeX either.

Comment: Good questions. I've done my preparation directly in LaTeX, but it is a little wordy for that purpose, even using auctex...

Comment: Did you try Pandoc? Not only does it itself convert Markdown+LaTeX to (whatever), but also, with its latest release, it lets you write scripts that work on the parse tree, so you could easily do what you want.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I'm going to try both pandoc and multimarkdown, probably this summer.

Comment: *so complex that there are no obvious faults* - I missed this pleasing reference first time I read it.

Comment: Don't know if this link is any help: http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/primarily-pandoc/

Comment: Nice to post an update after 1 year!

Comment: A bit unrelated, but I'm working on a [documentation compiler](https://github.com/ShabbyX/DocThis) which uses (very similar to) markdown in documentation. I have been thinking about adding tables to it, and I'm curious about knowing what syntax you have been using with that. Care to talk about it?

Comment: Maybe it's a bit late, but [ReText](http://retext.sourceforge.net/) or any other [pymarkups](https://launchpad.net/python-markups)-based editor supports math in Markdown with `mathjax` extension (included, but disabled by default).

Comment: Can someone explain how this question is off topic?

Comment: Nowadays, theres a better solution, very accurate and elegant: Using MathJax for MathML with markdown.
I've got the clue reading this article: http://jblevins.org/log/marked

Comment: Lunamark on Luatex - https://github.com/jgm/lunamark - is now the best way to integrate Markdown with a Tex engine.  That this question gives rise to Lua programming shows that it is on-topic and should be reopened.

Comment: wow this thread is way too old, i found it while looking infos about www.texts.io, hopefully u've found a solution till now

Comment: I think https://dropbox.com/paper is just the thing you are looking for @norman. It supports markdown and you can add scientific notations or whatever using latex inside markdown. Make sure to start with $$ and end with $$ as I recall.

Comment: @CharlesStewart does it work with github?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Have you tried with [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/)?

> **EDIT:**
>
> Although the documentation has become a bit complex, **pandoc** has supported *inline LaTeX* and *LaTeX templates* for 10 years.
>
> Documents like the following one can be written in *Markdown*:
>
> ```
> ---
> title: Just say hello!
> author: My Friend
> header-includes: |
>     \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
>     \usepackage{fancyhdr}
>     \pagestyle{fancy}
>     \fancyhead[CO,CE]{This is fancy}
>     \fancyfoot[CO,CE]{So is this}
>     \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
> abstract: This is a pandoc test with Markdown + inline LaTeX
> ---
>
> Just say hello!
> ===============
>
> This could be a good example or inlined \LaTeX:
>
> \begin{tikzpicture}
> \begin{axis}
> \addplot[color=red]{exp(x)};
> \end{axis}
> \end{tikzpicture}
> %Here ends the furst plot
> \hskip 5pt
> %Here begins the 3d plot
> \begin{tikzpicture}
> \begin{axis}
> \addplot3[
>     surf,
> ]
> {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
> \end{axis}
> \end{tikzpicture}
>
> And now, just a few words to terminate:
>
> > Goodbye folks!
> ```
>
> Which can be converted to LaTeX using commands like this: `pandoc -s -i Hello.md -o Hello.tex`
>
> Following is an image of the converted `Hello.md` to `Hello.pdf` file using **MiKTeX** as LaTeX processor with the command: `pandoc -s -i Hello.md -o Hello.pdf`
>
> [image]
>
> Finally, there are some open source *LaTeX templates* like this one: https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template, that can be used for better formatting.
>
> As always, the reader should dig deeper if he has less trivial use cases than presented here.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663532/lighweight-markup-wiki-language-for-documenting

Comment: You can also use RMarkdown directly. Pandoc uses it.

Comment: This is not a good answer. Does pandoc enable bits of Latex in markdown? This links a site that may not always be around. No elaboration on what pandoc even is. There should be some development to this answer.

Comment: EDIT: I have added a basic example for future references.

Comment: EDIT2:  I have added a screen capture with results.

Comment: (although this question is off topic for this site) -- That example is fine in this case, however if the LaTeX does not have some form (begin...end, math formula) then it would be necessary to explicitly mark the code block as LaTeX with ````​```{=latex} ...code... ```​```` (mentioned in pandoc manual: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-raw_attribute )

Answer (score 46):

Perhaps [mathJAX](http://www.mathjax.org/) is the ticket.  It's built on [jsMath](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/), a 2004 vintage JavaScript library.

As of 5-Feb-2015 I'd switch to recommend [KaTeX](https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/) - most performant Javascript LaTeX library from Khan Academy.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256433/how-to-show-math-equations-in-general-githubs-markdownnot-githubs-blog I'm also considering Katex server side, e.g. with https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/pull/3338

Answer (score 32):

Add the following code to the top of your Markdown files to get MathJax rendering support

```
<style TYPE="text/css">
code.has-jax {font: inherit; font-size: 100%; background: inherit; border: inherit;}
</style>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
        skipTags: ['script', 'noscript', 'style', 'textarea', 'pre'] // removed 'code' entry
    }
});
MathJax.Hub.Queue(function() {
    var all = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax(), i;
    for(i = 0; i < all.length; i += 1) {
        all[i].SourceElement().parentNode.className += ' has-jax';
    }
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"></script>
```

and then `$x^2$` or `$$x^2$$` will render as expected :-)

You can always install a local version of MathJax if you don't want to use the online distribution, but you might need to host it through a local webserver.

**UPDATE**: these days I just use [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demos.html) instead of canonical markdown, but the above is still useful.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Comment: re: note from the future. Current answer already incorporates a solution

Answer (score 12):

I'll answer your question with a counter-question...

What do you think of Org-mode?  It's not as pure as Markdown, but it is Markdown-like, and I find it as easy to work with, and it allows embedding of Latex.  Cf. http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Embedded-LaTeX.html

**Postscript**

In case you haven't looked at org-mode, it has one great strength as a general purpose "natural markup language" over Markdown, namely its treatment of tables.  The source:

```
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| -1 | 1 | 0 |
| -1 | -1 | 1 |
```

represents just what you think it will...

And the Latex is rendered in pieces using tex-mode's preview-latex.

Comment: I looked at org-mode, and although the embedded LaTeX seems very well done, it looks like total overkill for what I want (typical of emacs).
Interestingly, I note that the underlying rendering engine is again `dvipng`.  The table problem is an important one but I have already written a preprocessor to solve it :-)   +1

Answer (score 8):

you should look at multimarkdown http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/

it has support for metadata (headers, keywords, date, author, etc), tables, asciimath, mathml, hell i'm sure you could stick latex math code right in there. it's basically an extension to markdown to add all these other very useful features. It uses XSLT, so you can easily whip up your own LaTeX styles, and have it directly convert. I use it all the time, and I like it a lot.

I wish the markdown would just incorporate multimarkdown. it would be rather nice.

**Edit**: Multimarkdown will produce html, latex, and a few other formats. html can come  with a style sheet of your choice. it will convert into MathML as well, which displays in Firefox and Safari/Chrome, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Looks more complicated than what I want, and it's less than clear what the expressive power is (other than MathML is incorporated by reference0).

Answer (score 6):

[RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/) has a good free IDE that allows for Markdown and LaTeX.

Comment: But does it let you combine them in the same document/sentence, as the OP is asking to do?

Comment: You can embed equasions in markdown mode. See examples at http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/using_markdown_equations

Answer (score 6):

kramdown does exactly what you describe:

https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#math-blocks

And it's way more reliable and well-defined than Markdown.

Comment: it looks like this page is down at the moment, but here is the page that it used to 301 redirect to according to wayback machine: kramdown.gettalong.org:80/

Answer (score 3):

Hey, this might not be the most ideal solution, but it works for me. I ended up creating a Python-Markdown LaTeX extension.

https://github.com/justinvh/Markdown-LaTeX

It adds support for inline math and text expressions using a $math$ and %text% syntax. The extension is a preprocessor that will use latex/dvipng to generate pngs for the respective equations/text and then base64 encode the data to inline the images directly, rather than have external images.

The data is then put in a simple-delimited cache file that encodes the expression to the base64 representation. This limits the number of times latex actually has to be run.

Here is an example:

```
%Hello, world!% This is regular text, but this: $y = mx + b$ is not.
```

The output:

```
$ markdown -x latex test.markdown
<p><img class='latex-inline math-false' alt='Hello, world!' id='Helloworld' src='data:image/png;base64,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'> This is regular text, but this: <img class='latex-inline math-true' alt='y = mx + b' id='ymxb' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFIAAAAOBAMAAABOTlYkAAAAMFBMVEX///9ERETu7u4yMjK6urp2dnZUVFSIiIjMzMwQEBDc3NwiIiJmZmaYmJiqqqoAAADS00rKAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAOtJREFUKM9jYCAACsCk4wYGgiABTLInEKuS+QGxKvkVGBj47jBwI8tcffI84e45BoZ7GVcLECo9751iWLeSoRPITBQEggMMDBy9sxj2MDgz8DIE8yCpPMxwjWFBGUMMkpFcbAEMvxjKGLgYxIE8NkHBiYIyQMY+hmoGhi0Mdsi2czawbGCQBTJ+ILvzE0MaA9MHIIWwnWE9A+sBpk8LGDgmMCnAVXJNYPgCJHhRQvUiA/cDXoECZx4DXoSZTBtYgaaEPw5AVnkOGBRc5xTcbsReQrL9+nWwyxbgC88DcJZ+QygDcYD1+QPiFAIAtLA8KPZOGFEAAAAASUVORK5CYII='> is not.</p>
```

As you can see it is a verbose output, but that really isn't an issue since you're already using Markdown :)

Answer (score 2):

yes, but you'll have to hack it a little yourself. I've written a filter that replaces latex tags `$\some\inline\latex$` or `$$\some\equation$$` with appropriate image tags to a [mimetex.cgi](http://www.forkosh.dreamhost.com/source_mimetex.html) script. It took all of 5 minutes.

Warning: spectacularly ugly...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, markdown,re

MIMETEX_LOC="http://some.server.com/cgi-bin/mimetex.cgi"

def sanitizeLatex(text):
    return re.sub(r"\\",r"%5C", text)

def wrapLatexBlock(text):
    return '<img alt="equation" class="block" src="%s?%s"></img>'%(MIMETEX_LOC,text)

def wrapLatexInline(text):
    return '<img alt="equation" class="inline" src="%s?%s"></img>'%(MIMETEX_LOC,text)

def prepLatexBlock(matchobj):
    return wrapLatexBlock(sanitizeLatex(matchobj.group()[2:-2]))

def prepLatexInline(matchobj):
    return wrapLatexInline(sanitizeLatex(matchobj.group()[1:-1]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # initialise markdown
    md=markdown.Markdown()
    raw_md=open(sys.argv[1],"r").read()

    ##
    # deal with embedded latex
    ##
    raw_md=re.sub(r'\$\$(.*?)\$\$',prepLatexBlock, raw_md)
    raw_md=re.sub(r'\$(.*?)\$',prepLatexInline, raw_md)

    ##
    # once latex is parsed, convert md to html
    ##
    main_html=md.convert(raw_md)

    # hey presto!
    print(main_html)
```

Of course, you have to define the appropriate css yourself for .block and .inline images...

Answer (score 2):

I came across this discussion only now, so I hope my comment is still useful. I am involved with MathJax and, from how I understand your situation, I think that it would be a good way to solve the problem: you leave your LaTeX code as is, and let MathJax render the mathematics upon viewing.

Is there any reason why you would prefer images?

Comment: Certain Stack Exchange sites Math.Se, Physics.SE, etc... *do* use MathJax now, though the position of the management is that MathJax is too heavy to be deployed except where absolutely necessary. But that does not apply to presentations as it requires the works to run in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to parse Markdown in Lua using the Lunamark code (see its [Github repo](https://github.com/jgm/lunamark)), meaning that Markdown may be parsed directly by macros in Luatex and supports conversion to many of the formats supported by Pandoc (i.e., the library is well-suited to use in `lualatex`, `context`, Metafun, Plain Luatex, and `texlua` scripts).

The project was started by [John MacFarlane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1261777/john-macfarlane), author of Pandoc, and the tool's development tracks that of Pandoc quite closely and is of similar (i.e., excellent) quality.

[Khaled Hosny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2267847/khaled-hosny) wrote a Context module, providing convenient macro support.   [Michal's answer to the *Is there any package with Markdown support?* question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209971/175) gives code providing similar support for Latex.

Answer (score 1):

What language are you using?

If you can use ruby, then [maruku](http://maruku.rubyforge.org/) can be configured to process maths using various latex->MathML converters.  [Instiki](http://www.instiki.org/) uses this.  It's also possible to extend PHPMarkdown to use itex2MML as well to convert maths.  Basically, you insert extra steps in the Markdown engine at the appropriate points.

So with ruby and PHP, this is done.  I guess these solutions could also be adapted to other languages - I've gotten the itex2MML extension to produce perl bindings as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for exactly the same thing when I found [teqhtml](http://sourceforge.net/projects/teqhtml/). It does the conversion of $ and $$ equations to images with the nice bonus of aligning the resulting image vertically with the surrounding text. Not a lot of doc but it's quite straightforward.

Hope it helps some future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to rouse a really old thread, but I've been using [jemdoc](http://jemdoc.jaboc.net/) for a couple of years and it is really excellent.