# Eclipse with UML : Summation symbol writing

Tags: eclipse-plugin, markdown, modeling

[image: tla_class_diagram.png]I want to write below equation in my sample.md file .
I am using eclipse lunar 4.2 with UML (drawing modelling diagrams) .

[equation 1 in this paper](http://robots.stanford.edu/cs223b04/algo_tracking.pdf)

OR
[image: this equation]

I am trying this sample.md example

```
\defgroup ${MODULE} ${MODULE}
\ingroup low
\brief Example template module

${MODULE}
=========

Overview
--------

This module is intended as a template.

Details
------------------

@startuml{tla_class_diagram.png}

class SomeClass {
  uint32_t  mX
  uint32_t  mY
}
@enduml
```

Please tell me where to add the contents mention in below answer ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I mix LaTeX in with Markdown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188884/how-can-i-mix-latex-in-with-markdown)

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the header

```
<style TYPE="text/css">
code.has-jax {font: inherit; font-size: 100%; background: inherit; border: inherit;}
</style>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
        skipTags: ['script', 'noscript', 'style', 'textarea', 'pre'] // removed 'code' entry
    }
});
MathJax.Hub.Queue(function() {
    var all = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax(), i;
    for(i = 0; i < all.length; i += 1) {
        all[i].SourceElement().parentNode.className += ' has-jax';
    }
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

as in the duplicate answer and then use

```
`$\epsilon({\bf d}) = \epsilon(d_x, d_y) = \sum^{u_x+\omega_x}_{x=u_x-\omega_x} \sum^{u_x+\omega_y}_{y=u_x-\omega_y} ()I(x,y) - J({x+d_x,y}+d_y))^2$`
```

for the formula.

Comment: ,I am still not able to see the formula as per your suggestion .I have updated my question with my markdown file .Can you please update your answer with my markdown file .I am not including any header .Then where I can add your answer contents .I am new to this coding .please let me know your answer .

Comment: I have put that in a simple markdown editor and it showed up instantly. So I claim it to a poor markdown processor you use. Alternatively make a screenshot and put the png inside.

Comment: I have updated my png in my question ..it is just a example .I want to write the mentioned equation inside the markdown file which i can not till now .

Comment: I dont know the Eclipse markdown processor. Obviously it isn't worth much. Good luck then.