# Markdown and math formulas in C++ code with VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, markdown, formula

Is there a way to edit and render markdown or any other structured text format and math formulas in C++ code inside VS Code? I want to edit and view text and formulas inside VS Code editor, so there is no need for an external tool to view them in their target format. I know about some support for Doxygen comments, which are rendered in the tooltip, but it's limited and doesn't cover rendering of math formulas inside VS Code.

**EDIT**

In response to suggestion of having this question closed as redundant to [How can I mix LaTeX in with Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188884/how-can-i-mix-latex-in-with-markdown). My question is concerned with **markdown or any other structured text format and math formulas in C++ code** (see above), which is different from editing a pure markdown (*.md) file.

**EDIT**

In response to comments that my question is still not clear: **markdown or any other structured text format and math formulas in C++ code** means exactly that. The usual way markdown text is mixed into C++ are specially marked comments, but I'm not limiting my question to that. I would accept illegal C++ syntax, if it is preprocessed into legal C++ code by the build task.

For example, *.cpp file would contain these lines:

```
// $f(x) = \frac{2 \pi}{x}$
float f(x);
```

which would be displayed in VS Code editor as:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean inside comments in the source?

Comment: To my knowledge, Doxygen supports LaTeX embeds which includes support for its math formulae.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, inside VS Code. I edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: @paddy Correct, but Doxygen support is still quite limited and formulas are not rendered at the tooltip.

Comment: Try http://flennerhag.com/2017-01-14-latex/ and https://jekyllrb.com/docs/ maybe ? MathJax is essentially a JavaScript PNG renderer that turn your LaTex Snippets into high quality PNG images.

Comment: https://github.com/waylonflinn/markdown-it-katex looks good

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot I know about MathJax, but I don't see a way to use it in C++ code inside VS Code, which is my question.

Comment: @PaulJurczak For any editor, it won't work, you might want to use math symbol in unicode (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode); it's ugly, but it could be sometime better than latex code; for VScode, however, because it's all js and the code display is actually a webpage, katex seems ideal, and if no one wrote a plugin yet, it might be the opportunity. I'm certain it is possible.

Comment: for writing vscode extension: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot It definitely is possible, but I'm not willing to go that far, not in the near future anyway.

Comment: Everybody seems to only discuss "inside VS Code" and not "in C++ in VS Code". I think that is because it is not clear what you mean by that. Representing formulas in markdown/math in VS Code is one thing. Using formulas in C++ is something else. Please elaborate the difference you see and what exactly you want to achieve. (Note, I close-voted for lack of clarity, not for duplicate, which I am not convinced of.)

Comment: @Yunnosch I added en example. I don't think explaining what C++ code means in the context of VS Code.

Comment: @PaulJurczak You might have your answer, if not an update here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3220
and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/66418
and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/85682.

What you write in comments is stripped away by the preprocessor, so in a way it's not c++ code, it's code comments in general; extensions doing something similar are language agnostic because of this (they look for a certain regex pattern and then use the IDE api to insert image/html/etc).